# How to get installed packages in android?

Tags: android

I can get my code to get all installed packages and display them in a toast. The problem is, I want my code to only display the package name containing a string  in it. How do I do that?

```
ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager)
    getApplicationContext().getSystemService( getApplicationContext().ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

for(int pnum = 0; pnum < procInfos.size(); pnum++)
{
 if((procInfos.get(pnum)).processName.contains("android")||    (procInfos.get(pnum)).processName.contains("system")||(procInfos.get(pnum)).processName.contains("huawei")||(procInfos.get(pnum)).processName.contains("adil")) 
 {
      //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "system apps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
else
{
    actvityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(procInfos.get(pnum).processName);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "killed "+procInfos.get(pnum).processName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
 }
```

Comment: "I can get my code to get all installed packages and display them in a toast" -- your code has nothing to do with that.

Comment: It looks like you are getting running processes, not installed packages.

Comment: Oh my bad, let me update

Comment: there and there! now it is supposed to do as advertised on the tin

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code that will give u all installed activities/applications on Android:

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List<ResolveInfo> pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
```

Getting the list of installed non-system apps:

```
public static void installedApps()
{
List<PackageInfo> packList = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
for (int i=0; i < packList.size(); i++)
{
    PackageInfo packInfo = packList.get(i);
    if (  (packInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0)
    {
        String appName = packInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
        Log.e("App № " + Integer.toString(i), appName);
    }
} }
```

OR you can try a well structured example:

```
class PInfo {
private String appname = "";
private String pname = "";
private String versionName = "";
private int versionCode = 0;
private Drawable icon;
private void prettyPrint() {
    Log.v(appname + "\t" + pname + "\t" + versionName + "\t" + versionCode);
} }

private ArrayList<PInfo> getPackages() {
ArrayList<PInfo> apps = getInstalledApps(false); 
final int max = apps.size();
for (int i=0; i<max; i++) {
    apps.get(i).prettyPrint();
}
return apps; }

private ArrayList<PInfo> getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages) {
ArrayList<PInfo> res = new ArrayList<PInfo>();        
List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
    PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
    if ((!getSysPackages) && (p.versionName == null)) {
        continue ;
    }
    PInfo newInfo = new PInfo();
    newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
    newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
    newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
    newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
    newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
    res.add(newInfo);
    }
return res; }
```